# Chai's expect equivalent of Node's assert.ifError

Tags: node.js, chai

What is chai's expect equivalent of Node's built in [assert.ifError](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_iferror_value) method?

I'd like to convert a project completely from Node's built in assertion lib to chai's expect lib.

Answer (score 0):

Chai's exists method, is what you're looking for

https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_exists